# Watch is not running

Tags: gulp

I'm working on images. The task: gulp-images works as expected. But when I try to use the watch task by running "gulp" on the console nothings happens.

Can someone suggest a solution?

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var imageResize = require('gulp-image-resize');
var gm = require('gulp-gm');

gulp.task('images', function () {
    return gulp.src('/daten/gulp-work/*.{jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG}')
        .pipe(imageResize({
            width: 800,
            height: 600,
            crop: false,
            upscale: true,
            quality: 0.5
        }))
        .pipe(imagemin({ progressive: true }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('/daten/gulp-work/final/'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
return gulp.watch('/daten/gulp-work/*.{jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG}', ['images']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch', 'images']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure but i think the problem is with the return in the watch task.

try like this

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('/daten/gulp-work/*.{jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG}', ['images']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch', 'images']);
```

**UPDATE**

the actual gulp version, 3.9.1 dosen't watch for new files. Version 4 introduces this feature see github.com/rehabstudio/fe-skeleton/issues/36 for details

Comment: Hi rick, no i tried it without the return. Got the same results.

Comment: and second thing? what do you expect as result, cause at launch that kind of task give an output like [17:59:18] Using gulpfile ~/DEV/statbriks/gulpfile.js
[17:59:18] Starting 'wtc'...
[17:59:18] Finished 'wtc' after 16 ms

Comment: I have a bunch of images. And when i save those in the Source-Dir i expect that the task images is run.

And everytime i save the next images ....


The watch task alone says:
[19:29:07] Starting 'watch'...
[19:29:07] Finished 'watch' after 73 ms

Comment: the actual gulp version, 3.9.1 dosen't watch for new files. Version 4 introduces this feature see https://github.com/rehabstudio/fe-skeleton/issues/36 for details

Comment: Oh rick thx. 
[19:38:47] CLI version 3.9.1
[19:38:47] Local version 3.9.1
Wrong version

Comment: easy, once I got what the problem is it was better :) I've got the same problem too